# How can I restart or close then turn on an SKScene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am not looking to remove all children in the SkScene, I want to completely close the scene once the game is over.

Yes I have tried all of the solutions posted here, need some way of either completely restarting the app or restarting a single scene.

Transition Code:

```
let game = Menu(fileNamed: "Menu")!

game.scaleMode = .aspectFill

let trans = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1.0)

self.view?.presentScene(game, transition:  trans)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you normally have a `GameOverScene`, or some such, and transition to that?  Then onto a `MainMenuScene` and eventually back to the `GameScene`?

Comment: Yes Indeed, however the issue is the skscene persists, all the timers and persist no matter what I do unless the app is completely restarted. I can stop nodes and such actions from moving or spawning. However If I change sprites image or anything it doesnt work, unless the app is restarted manually.

Comment: OK sounds like you need to show your scene transition logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 (SpriteKit): Reseting the GameScene after the game ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649446/swift-3-spritekit-reseting-the-gamescene-after-the-game-ends)

Comment: Have you checked if you have a memory leak?

Comment: I have posted my transition code, also I have seen the other post, however, it does not solve my issue.

Comment: I have not checked memory leak, not really sure how to.