# Swift: multiple sprite kit game scenes, loading in game scenes from view controller?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Alright, so I have sprite kit game in Swift and I've created my game in the `GameScene.swift` file that apple sets up for you, and that all works great. Now I want to create another game scene within this same project.

When the game is over, right now the game moves to a new UIViewController (named `GameOverBufferViewController`) that I've set up in the storyboard. But I want it to move to a completely new game scene.

So I looked at how `GameViewController` loads in `GameScene.swift` (because the game scenes need a view controller as well as the `SKScene` code) and copied it into the view controller file for my UIViewController that the game moves to when it's game over.

I changed the references to `GameScene` to match my new game scene swift file (`GameOverScene1`) and the `unarchiveFromFile` func to avoid an error:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile2(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData!)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameOverScene1
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}


class GameOverBufferViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if let scene = GameOverScene1.unarchiveFromFile2("GameOverScene1") as? GameOverScene1 {
            // Configure the view.

            let skView = self.view as! SKView

            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true
            skView.showsPhysics = false

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)

        }


    }
```

Then here I set up my `GameOverScene1.swift` file:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameOverScene1: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        //Do stuff in scene
        println("it works!")
    }
}
```

And the game runs without any errors or crashing but `GameOverScene1` isn't run; it just goes to `GameOverBufferViewController`. Nothing is printed to the console either.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT********

This is what my `GameOverBufferViewController` file looks like now and I get a `SIGABRT` error saying `could not cast a UIView as an SKView`:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameOverBufferViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            // Configure the view.

            back()


    }
    func back() {
        view.subviews.map({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

        let theView = view as! SKView //error on this line
        let theMainMenu = GameOverScene( size: view.frame.size )
        theMainMenu.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill

        theView.presentScene( theMainMenu )

    }
```

Comment: In your storyboard, make sure the new view controller's view's class is `SKView` not `UIView`. Alternatively, you can present a new scene with the original view controller.

Comment: How would I present an SKScene manually?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111935/how-to-transition-scenes-in-swift

Comment: @0x141E can you look at my most recent question? Still having trouble

Comment: @skyguy Did my updated solution below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I just use this:

```
func back() {
    let theView = view as! SKView
    let theMainMenu = MainMenu( size: view.frame.size )
    theMainMenu.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill

    theView.presentScene( theMainMenu )
}
```

`MainMenu` is a subclass of `SKScene`.

EDIT:

Make sure you are declaring your view as a `UIView` when your main `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` function runs. Like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let theView = view as! SKView
    let theWelcome = Welcome( size: view.bounds.size )
    theWelcome.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill

    theView.presentScene( theWelcome )
}
```

Comment: Where are you declaring/calling the back() func? I updated my question with what I put in my GameOverBufferViewcontroller and I'm getting an error

Comment: In my main ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    let SceneMove = SceneName(size: self.scene!.size)
    SceneMove.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    self.scene!.view!.presentScene(SceneMove)
```

SceneName is of course the name of your scene.

Credit From skyguy and the link he posted: [How to transition scenes in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111935/how-to-transition-scenes-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from your "unarchiveFromFile" function of the extension SKNode.

Try to change this line:

```
let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameOverScene1
```

to this :

```
let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! SKScene
```

Also note that you do not need to have many "unarchiveFromFile" functions for each new scene (each new level), just define one after your imports in the GameViewController class.