# Change SKScene using presentScene()

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

In my SpriteKit Game i'm using:

```
    self.scene!.removeFromParent()
    let skView = self.view! as SKView
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    var scene: PlayScene!
    scene = PlayScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithColor(SKColor(red: 25.0/255.0, green: 55.0/255.0, blue: 12.0/255.0, alpha: 1), duration: 1.0))
```

to move from one scene to another. But how can I go back to the original scene? Using the same principle of code always led to a major crash..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made an example where global structure is used to track the info about `previousScene`. It can be done with a custom property as well, or by using userData which every node has. The logic is the same. Also, I've removed debugging code (debug label code etc.) because it is not important for everything to work.

Example might be better if I added a few buttons where each links to the certain scene, but I left just one button to keep everything short as possible.

What you need to know about this example (you will change this rules according to your game, but the logic is the same - set the previousScene before an actual transition):

- there are three scenes, WelcomeScene (default one), MenuScene and a GameScene.
- tapping on the black button takes you to the GameScene. There is an exception to this rule when current scene is a GameScene. In that case, transition will take you to the previousScene.
- tapping anywhere around the black button will take you to the previous scene. There is an exception to this rule when WelcomeScene is loaded for the first time (previousScene is not set) and a transition will take you to the MenuScene in that case.

-in your GameViewController you should set up a WelcomeScene to be a default one. Otherwise, you should change a code a bit to handle situations what happening when previousScene is not set (like I did in touchesBegan of WelcomeScene).

So those are rules I've made, just in order to make all those transitions a bit more meaningful...

Here is the code (BaseScene.swift):

```
import SpriteKit

enum SceneType: Int {

    case WelcomeScene   = 0
    case MenuScene      //1
    case GameScene      //2  
}

struct GlobalData
{
    static var previousScene:SceneType?
    //Other global data...
}

class BaseScene:SKScene {

    let button = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        setupButton()
    }

    private func setupButton(){

        if (button.parent  == nil){

            //Just setup button properties like position, zPosition and name

            button.name = "goToGameScene"
            button.zPosition = 1
            button.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: 100)
            addChild(button)
        }
    }

    func goToScene(newScene: SceneType){

        var sceneToLoad:SKScene?

        switch newScene {

        case SceneType.GameScene:

            sceneToLoad = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")

        case SceneType.MenuScene:

            sceneToLoad = MenuScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene")

        case SceneType.WelcomeScene:

            sceneToLoad = WelcomeScene(fileNamed:"WelcomeScene")

        }

        if let scene = sceneToLoad {

            scene.size = size
            scene.scaleMode = scaleMode
            let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(3)
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
}
```

Every scene (WelcomeScene, MenuScene, GameScene) inherits from a BaseScene class (which is subclass of a SKScene). I guess, there is no need to explain that, but feel free to ask if something confuses you. The important method here (which is used by every subclass) is goToScene(scene:SceneType) and its parameter (of type SceneType) which tells us what type of scene a method should load.

SceneType is just an enum which holds integers...So actually we are not working with objects here, thus there is no fear of [strong reference cycles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Next, there are other scenes (WelcomeScene.swift):

```
import SpriteKit


class WelcomeScene:BaseScene {


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        super.didMoveToView(view)

        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.darkGrayColor() 
    }

    deinit {print ("WelcomeScene deinited")}

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first

        if let location = touch?.locationInNode(self){

            //Give a priority to a button - if button is tapped go to GameScene
            let node = nodeAtPoint(location)
            if node.name == "goToGameScene"{
                GlobalData.previousScene = SceneType.MenuScene
                goToScene(SceneType.GameScene)
            }else{
                //Otherwise, do a transition to the previous scene

                //Get the previous scene
                if let previousScene = GlobalData.previousScene {

                    GlobalData.previousScene = SceneType.WelcomeScene
                    goToScene(previousScene)

                }else{

                    // There is no previousScene set yet? Go to MenuScene then...
                    GlobalData.previousScene = SceneType.WelcomeScene
                    goToScene(SceneType.MenuScene)

                }
            }       
        }      
    }
}
```

To keep short as possible, everything is commented. Next code (MenuScene.swift):

```
import SpriteKit

class MenuScene: BaseScene  {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        super.didMoveToView(view)
        backgroundColor = SKColor.purpleColor()
    }

    deinit {
        print ("MenuScene deinited") //If this method isn't called, you might have problems with strong reference cycles.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first

        if let location = touch?.locationInNode(self){

            //Give a priority to a button - if button is tapped go to GameScene
            let node = nodeAtPoint(location)
            if node.name == "goToGameScene"{
                GlobalData.previousScene = SceneType.MenuScene
                goToScene(SceneType.GameScene)
            }else{
                //Otherwise, do a transition to the previous scene

                //Get the previous scene
                if let previousScene = GlobalData.previousScene {

                    GlobalData.previousScene = SceneType.MenuScene
                    goToScene(previousScene)

                } 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

And for the end (GameScene.swift):

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: BaseScene{

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        super.didMoveToView(view)

     self.backgroundColor = SKColor.orangeColor() 
    }

    deinit {print ("GameScene deinited")}

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        //Here, we ignore black button because we don't want to transition to the same scene

         if let previousScene = GlobalData.previousScene {

            GlobalData.previousScene = SceneType.GameScene
            goToScene(previousScene)  
        }
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image: transitions]

Just read again the rules from the beginning and you will be fine (eg. in GameScene black button doesn't work, or on first launch previousScene is not set , so you will be transitioned to the MenuScene by default).

That would be it. Hope this helps a bit. You can copy and paste the code to test it and improve it to your needs. Still, not sure that you really need this. It looks that you just need to [correctly transition between scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24112335/3402095).

**HINT:** What is important here is that every scene BaseScene, WelcomeScene... has it own .sks file. You create those from File->New->File->Resource and name it appropriately (like BaseClass.sks, WelcomeScene.sks...) Also, it is your job to maintain the state of `GlobalData.previousScene` variable (eg. set it before the transition is made).

Comment: It works! thank you so much! Exactly what i needed :))

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a property in your new scene that stores the previous one, something like `previousScene`. Then you can set it like this: `scene.previousScene = self.scene`. In you new scene, you can now go back to the previous scene with `skView.presentScene(previousScene)`

And I'd advise against naming the new scene you are going to present `scene` because your current scene is also named scene, so if you accidentally forget the `self` in `self.scene` then that may cause a lot of confusion. I'd name it something like `newScene` or `sceneToPresent`.

Also, your first line, `self.scene!.removeFromParent()`, isn't necessary. You don't need to remove the current scene before presenting a new one.

Comment: No problem! Remember to select this as the right answer if it worked :)

Comment: @Addison While this might work as an solution to track the previous scene, it will create a strong reference cycle and previous scene will never be released after the transition (deinit() will not be called). There is no need to keep a whole scene object in memory just in order to make a transition to a new (previous) scene.

Comment: @Whirlwind So would making it a weak reference fix that problem?

Comment: @Whirlwind it would be nice if you could post an answer including the right snipped of code

Comment: @Addison In short, no. Weak reference does not stop ARC of disposing of the referenced instance. This is what will happen: You will set a scene.previousScene = self.scene, but after transition a current scene will be deinited, and automatically scene.previousScene will be set to nil...

Comment: @user3138007 When I need to track the previous scene, I usually do what Addison pointed. I create myScene.sceneToLoad property, but instead of storing a real scene, I create an enum called SceneType and store simple integer. If you still need a code example, let me know.

Comment: @Whirlwind yeah a code example would be helpful! Although I got your point I'm not quite sure how to set the actual code up... for the best way to easily change between multiple scenes. Thank You!

Comment: @user3138007 Okay, will make an example shortly ...But from your last comment I am having an impression that you are not trying to track the previous scene (after each transition), but rather just to transition to a particular scene(s)... Anyways, I will try to make both examples (probably is going to be a huge answer :))